# How to isolate file permission and file name from results of ls -l?

Tags: command-line, permissions, files, ls

I want see only the file name and the corresponding file permission. How to do that?

ls -l gives

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jb jb    102 Apr 28 12:48  hello2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jb jb    102 Apr 28 12:53  hello.txt
```

I would like to see as below

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1  hello2.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1  hello.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pipe it to `gawk` and output the fields you want, something like this or similar:

```
ls -l | gawk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $9}'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `stat` command is made for this ex.:

```
stat -c '%A %n' *.txt
```

or

```
stat --printf '%A\t%n\n' *.txt
```

where the format specifiers have the following meanings

```
   %A     access rights in human readable form
   %n     file name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get most of the way there by using `ls` itself: `ls -lGg --time-style=+` will print only the access modes, link count, size and name.

Processing `ls` output is tricky because filenames can contain pretty much anything, so you can't assume anything about them when processing. It would be better to use `find` instead to print exactly the information needed using [`-printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Ownership-Directives):

```
find . -printf '%M %p\n'
```

(With options like `-maxdepth` used as appropriate to limit the listing.)

Comment: "ls: unrecognized option '--time-format=+'" error for me when I try your ls command.

Comment: Ah, should have been `--time-style`